# Please elaborate on the concept of equivalence classes.

Tags: equivalence-relations

I think I know hwo to prove reflexive, symmetric, and transitive properties but please show me how to do equivalence classes or describe them.

Let n ∈ N. Define relation Rn on Z by (x, y) ∈ Rn if and only if $x^2 − y^2$
is divisible by n. Prove that Rn is an equivalence relation.
(a) Let n = 4. How many equivalence classes are there? Describe the equivalence classes in the simplest possible way.
(b) Let n = 5. How many equivalence classes are there? Describe the equivalence classes in the simplest possible way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

These relations say $x$ and $y$ are equivalent if and only if $x^2\equiv y^2\mod n$. Hence the equivalence classes corresp.ond to the congruence classes of the squares modulo $n$.

For instance, modulo $4$ the squares are congruent either to $0$ or to $1$. So there are two equivalence classes: `even` numbers have squares congruent to $0\bmod 4$ and `odd` numbers, squares congruent to $1 \bmod 4$.

Comment: The question is about behaviour modulo 5, Is it easy to describe from mod 4 behaviour?

Comment: @PVanchinathan: The question seemed to be about both mod $4$ and mod $5$. I purposely showed only the method for $4$. It is similar for mod $5$: compute the squares mod $5$ and try to find a simple description as simple as possible for numbers having the same square mod $5$.

Comment: two equivalence as in even numbers and odd numbers? because X, Y should be divided into two classes here, not their squares? thanks

Comment: I don't understand your objection. In the case of mod $4$ the classes are indeed even and odd numbers. The case of mod $5$ is of course different: there are $3$ classes, since there are three squares mod $5$: $0, 1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the number $n=5$ is a prime number. We want $x^2-y^2$ to be a multiple of $5$ which means $5$ should divide the product of the two numbers $x-y$ and $x+y$.

This boils down to one of them being a multiple of $5$,
Choose any $x$. Then choose  every possible $y$ such that $x-y$ or $x+y$ should be amultiple of $5$, By looking at the last digit of $x$, you can figure out how to list all such $y$'d for a given $x$.

Comment: got it and how would i figure out the equivalence classes?